# get form value (mysql_insert_id) after the form submitted using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to get a value (mysql_insert_id) after my form was submitted by ajax and form validation (jquery.validationEngine) but without success..

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $("#form1").validationEngine('attach',
        {
            autoHidePrompt:true,showOneMessage:true,
            onValidationComplete: function(form, status)
                {
                    if(status === true)
                        {

                           formget(document.getElementById('form1'),'page.php');

           TINY.box.show({html:'The entry (i want the id here..) has been updated successfully!',animate:false,close:false,mask:false,boxid:'success',autohide:2,top:5});
}
          else
{
          TINY.box.show({html:'Please check the form and try  again',animate:false,close:false,mask:false,boxid:'error',autohide:2,top:5});
}
}  
});
```

My page.php file

```
$query="INSERT INTO users (userid,title,)VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id']."', '".$_REQUEST['title']."')"; $result=mysql_query($query);
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: Please note that PHP's `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and not recommended for use. Code should be amended to use the newer `mysqli` or `PDO` extensions instead.

Comment: yes i know - mysqli_insert_id(). :-)

Comment: Please also be aware that using `$_SESSION` and `$_REQUEST` in an `INSERT` query whitout sanitizing the user submitted data could lead to **serious** security issue and expose your application to MySQL injection attacks.

Have a look at [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: no one can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="INSERT INTO users (userid,title,)VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id']."', '".$_REQUEST['title']."')"; $result=mysql_query($query);
$id = mysql_insert_id();
echo mysql_error();
```

look at the error message;

Comment: everything working good for me i just can't get the value ($id) back that i can use it for other function.